# Python/Django: 403 error when third-party website makes POST call

Tags: python, django

I have a django application where a user registers and associates a third-party account using OAuth. As part of this, I create a subscription on the third-party website that will make a POST request to given endpoint whenever there is some event at third-party website. When the third-party website makes a POST call, I get following error -

`"POST /notification HTTP/1.1" 403 2282`

And, if I understand it right, it is because the `csrf` token is missing in the request. How do I ignore `csrf` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [`@crsf_exempt` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) to your view function:

> This decorator marks a view as being exempt from the protection ensured by the middleware. Example:
>
> ```
> from django.http import HttpResponse
> from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
>
> @csrf_exempt
> def my_view(request):
>     return HttpResponse('Hello world')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore csrf in all forms, in settings.py comment this line in your list of middleware classes.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ....
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ....
)
```